# You can't specify target table 'assets' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql

My query.

```
UPDATE assets SET assets.Amount = (SELECT SUM(assets.Amount) - NEW.Amount FROM assets WHERE NEW.UserId =   assets.UserId and NEW.AccountId = assets.AccountId) AS TmpAssets
WHERE NEW.UserId = assets.UserId and NEW.AccountId = assets.AccountId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not allow you to use the table being updated in a subquery in an `update` or `delete`.  It is easy enough to get around this.

Here is one approach using `update`/`join`:

```
UPDATE assets a JOIN
       (select sum(a.Amount) as sumamount, a.UserId, a.AccountId
        from assets a
        where NEW.UserId = a.UserId and NEW.AccountId = a.AccountId
        group by a.UserId, a.AccountId
       ) anew
       on NEW.UserId = a.UserId and NEW.AccountId = a.AccountId
    SET a.Amount = anew.sumamount - new.Amount;
```

Comment: Nice query, but I have a problem. I have 2 records on table with amount 20 and 30, the 2 amount changed with new entry, I need totals of two records(50) then changed. very need help

Comment: @PutraLZendrato . . . Then change the subquery to aggregate the values you want.  This version seems to do what you are trying to do with the query in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can't do that becuase you are sub-selecting from the table while updating it.
Best you can do is create a tmp table and exec the subquery from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 UPDATE assets SET assets.Amount = (select temp.val from (SELECT (SUM(assets.Amount) - 
 NEW.Amount) val from assets   WHERE
 NEW.UserId =   assets.UserId and NEW.AccountId = assets.AccountId) temp) 
 WHERE NEW.UserId = assets.UserId and NEW.AccountId = assets.AccountId ;
```